# Find a char or substring with specifying start pos

Tags: c++

I couldn't find a function which would let me specify the start pos for beginning a char or substring search.

I have, for example:

```
char *c = "S1S2*S3*S4";
```

I'd like search for '`S3`' by searching the first '`*`' asterisk and then the second asterisk following it and finally getting the substring '`S3`' enclosed by those asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to find the location of the first asterisk, then the location of the second asterisk. Then use those positions as the start and end locations to search for `S3`.

Comment: Use two pointers.  The second search uses the result of the first search.  char *first, *second;  first = strchr(c, '*'); second = strchr(first+1, '*');

Comment: @cpx: Because of the way C-strings work, `c+5` is another valid C-string with contents `"S3*S4"`.  But since you tagged the question C++, I recommend avoiding C-string manipulations and using the `string` class.

Answer (score 9):

The [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class has a large `find` family of functions that take an index as a second argument.  Repeated applications of `find('*', index)` should get you what you need.

```
std::string s(c);
std::string::size_type star1 = s.find('*');
std::string::size_type star2 = s.find('*', star1 + 1);
std::string last_part = s.substr(star2 + 1);
```

Comment: It would be proper to check `star1` and `star2` against `std::string::npos`. Other than that I would recommend this C++ solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
char *strchr( const char *str, int ch );
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/) for reference

Comment: It doesn't let me specify the index to begin search for second asterisk.

Comment: @cpx use pointer arithmetic.  if "p" is your char pointer and "*" is located at 3 then `strchar( p+2, '*' )`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>

std::string between_asterisks( const std::string& s ) {
    std::string::size_type ast1 = s.find('*');
    if (ast1 == std::string::npos) {
        throw some_exception();
    }
    std::string::size_type sub_start = ast1+1;
    std::string::size_type ast2 = s.find('*', sub_start);
    if (ast2 == std::string::npos) {
        throw some_exception();
    }
    return s.substr(sub_start, ast2-sub_start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strchr(). Simply save the returned pointer and pass it to the next call. As this pointer points to the occurence of your search, the search will start from there.

Answer (score 0):

well one possibility - if you are to use c-style char* arrays for strings - is to use strchr to search for the occurrences of the asterisks, e.g., (and with NO error checking, mind)

```
 char c []= "S1S2*S3*S4";

 char* first = strchr(c,'*');
 if (first) {
   char* start = ++first;
   char* nextast = strchr(start,'*');
   char* s3str = new char[nextast-start+1];
   strncpy(s3str,start,nextast-start);
   s3str[next-start] = '\0';
 }
```

But it would be easier to use the C++ string class to do this.